# Need a better way to append a large body of code

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, jquery-ui, google-chrome-extension

For some reason this code stops working once it is appended.  I plan on adding even more to this huge mess of barley human readable code.  If someone could explain to me why this code doesn't work and how I could better append this that would be great.  This is for a chrome extension where this code injects itself into a website so it needs to be appended to exist.  The portion of the code that is not working for me is the function that is supposed to hide and show the divs inside the main-menu div.

```js
$(function() {
 var startmenuicon = $('#topCenter');
 $(startmenuicon).prepend('<img id="du" src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/BRILLIANT/food/png/400/beer.png" title="Click me!" />');
});

$(function () {
$('#mainul a').click(function(e){
     hideContentDivs();
     var tmp_div = $(this).parent().index();
     $('.maine div').eq(tmp_div).show();
  });

function hideContentDivs(){
    $('.maine div').each(function(){
    $(this).hide();});
}
hideContentDivs();
});

$(function () {
 var maindiv = $('<div id="main-menu"><button id="close" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 18px; cursor: pointer;  cursor: hand;" onclick="$(this).parent().hide();">X</button><div id="navigation"><nav><ul id="mainul"><li><a href="#">Options</a><span class="dropBottom"></span><ul><li><a href="#" id="link1">Change bg img</a></li><li><a href="#" id="link2">Shot Counter</a></li><li><a href="#" id="link3">Shot Timer</a></li><li><a href="#" id="link4">Embed </a></li><li><a href="#" id="link5">About</a></li><li><a href="#" id="link6">Contact</a></li></ul></ul></nav><div class="maine"><div id="page1" class="content"><h1>Page 1</h1><p>First Section of content.</p></div><div id="page2" class="content"><h1>Page 2</h1><p>Second section of content</p></div><div id="page3" class="content"><h1>Page 3</h1><p>Third section of content</p></div><div id="page4" class="content"><h1>Page 4</h1><p>Fourth section of content</p></div><div id="page5" class="content"><h1>Page 5</h1><p>Fifth section of content</p></div><div id="page6" class="content"><h1>Page 6</h1><p>Six section of content</p></div></div></div>')
 
 $('#du').click(function() {
  var mainwindow = $('body');
  $(mainwindow).append(maindiv);
  $(maindiv).draggable({containment: 'body', scroll: false }).resizable({minWidth: 412, minHeight: 418, containment: 'body'});
 });

 $('#du').click(function() {
  $(maindiv).show();
 });
});
```

Comment: I mean I need to have this huge body of code (the maindiv variable) dynamically added to the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were using multiple `$(function(){});` I tried reorganizing things, and also used *event delegation* to target "non-existing-yet" elements (`#mainul a`), like this:

```
$('body').on('click', '#mainul a', function(){});
```

Try it:

```js
$(function() {
  var startmenuicon = $('#topCenter');
  $(startmenuicon).prepend('<img id="du" src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/BRILLIANT/food/png/400/beer.png" title="Click me!" />');

  var maindiv = $('<div id="main-menu"><button id="close" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 18px; cursor: pointer;  cursor: hand;" onclick="$(this).parent().hide();">X</button><div id="navigation"><nav><ul id="mainul"><li><a href="#">Options</a><span class="dropBottom"></span><ul><li><a href="#" id="link1">Change bg img</a></li><li><a href="#" id="link2">Shot Counter</a></li><li><a href="#" id="link3">Shot Timer</a></li><li><a href="#" id="link4">Embed </a></li><li><a href="#" id="link5">About</a></li><li><a href="#" id="link6">Contact</a></li></ul></ul></nav><div class="maine"><div id="page1" class="content"><h1>Page 1</h1><p>First Section of content.</p></div><div id="page2" class="content"><h1>Page 2</h1><p>Second section of content</p></div><div id="page3" class="content"><h1>Page 3</h1><p>Third section of content</p></div><div id="page4" class="content"><h1>Page 4</h1><p>Fourth section of content</p></div><div id="page5" class="content"><h1>Page 5</h1><p>Fifth section of content</p></div><div id="page6" class="content"><h1>Page 6</h1><p>Six section of content</p></div></div></div>');

  $('body').on('click', '#mainul a', function(e) {
    hideContentDivs();
    var tmp_div = $(e.currentTarget).parent().index();
    console.log($(e.target));
    $('.maine div').eq(tmp_div).show();
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  function hideContentDivs() {
    $('.maine div').hide();
  }
  
  hideContentDivs();
  
  $('#du').click(function() {
    var mainwindow = $('body');
    $(mainwindow).append(maindiv);
    $(maindiv).draggable({
      containment: 'body',
      scroll: false
    }).resizable({
      minWidth: 412,
      minHeight: 418,
      containment: 'body'
    });
    $(maindiv).show();
  });
});
```

```css
#topCenter {
    width: 30%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
}
#main-menu {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
    margin-top: -120px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
#mainul li {
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 1em;
}
img {
  height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="topCenter"></div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't the case.  The portion of the code that does not work for me is not the draggable portion.  It's the portion of the code that is suppose to show and hide the div's.  I should have specified that in my original post.